# how use Distance Matrix API in Flutter web,

Tags: flutter, web, google-api, cors

I am currently using the Google Matrix API in a Flutter web application and have encountered a CORS error. I have managed to resolve this issue locally by adding the '--disable-web-security' flag in 'flutter\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\web'. However, I don't know how use it without server side. I use Firebase Functions as DB. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.